# Converting nested JSON into Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm receiving a string server side which I then convert to JSON:

`127.0.0.1:8000/devices/f751/?json={ "DeviceId":"192-2993-2993", "Date":"1/4/2019 9:52:2", "Location":"-1.000000000,-1.000000000", "Key":"{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}", "Data":" { \"Value0\":\"{ \"ReferenceValue\":\"Elevation\", \"Prediction\":\"22.216558464\"}\", \"Value1\":\"{ \"ReferenceValue\":\"Wind Speed\", \"Prediction\":\"42.216558464\"}\" } "}`

After conversion using `json.loads()` I get the following output:

```
updatedRequest = json.loads(jsonRequest)
updatedRequest 
{'DeviceId': '192-2993-2993',
'Date': '1/4/2019 9:52:2',
'Location': '-1.000000000,-1.000000000',
'Key': '{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}',
'Data': '{ "Value0":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Elevation", "Prediction":"22.216558464"}", "Value1":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Wind Speed", "Prediction":"42.216558464"}" }'}
```

So far so good, I can access the Data value via `updatedRequest['Data']`.

```
updatedRequest['Data']

'{ "Value0":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Elevation", "Prediction":"22.216558464"}", "Value1":"{ "ReferenceValue":"Wind Speed", "Prediction":"42.216558464"}" }'
```

My issue when attempting to convert this into a Python usable dictionary (e.g `updatedRequest['Data']['Value0']['ReferenceValue']`). Because there is an unknown number of 'Value' keys, I'm uncertain as to what the best procedure would be to move this into workable data.

Comment: What is producing this data? It's malformed; the "Data" key is being sent as a single string, so it's double-serialized. And anyway that should be a list of dicts not a single dict.

Comment: I attempted at creating a proper MCVE here, but your JSON value is not actually valid JSON, there can't be newlines inside the `"` quotes. You have a **nested* JSON document, you want to decode `updatedRequest['Data']` too.

Comment: I'm receiving it as an argument in a POST request:

i.e. 127.0.0.1:8000/devices/f751/?json={ "DeviceId":"751-002-NEWBD4", "Date":"1/4/2019 9:52:2", "Location":"-1.000000000,-1.000000000", "Key":"{53280F0F-6D93-449B-B445-B7A4F1BF1BCB}", "Data":" { \"Value0\":\"{ \"ReferenceValue\":\"TempC\", \"Prediction\":\"22.216558464\"}\", \"Value1\":\"{ \"ReferenceValue\":\"Dry Matter\", \"Prediction\":\"42.216558464\"}\" } "}

Comment: @Hikalea: that'd be a nested JSON document if it wasn't malformed. There is a nested `}` in there that completely breaks things.

Comment: But if you are receiving JSON on one line, don't add newlines into this format without understanding what you are doing. There are no newlines in that query string.

Comment: It appears that `updatedRequest['Data']` is *meant* to be a JSON document itself, but if that's the case, than it is malformed, as there are `\\` backslashes missing to escape the `"` values inside the further level of nesting of JSON documents. `"Value0"` and `"Value1"` both reference *another* JSON document nested in the nested JSON document but the quoting to make that work is missing entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately SO totally destroyed my formatting so I'm having trouble discerning what is terribly written and what is being altered, I've updated the original post. Which nested } would fix my issue if removed?

Comment: If that's the case then *we can't  help here*. The value is broken, you are being served invalid data, repairing that data is not going to be easy, if possible at all. We don't know what produced that broken value so we can't meaningfully advice on how to repair this.

Comment: If I understand what is improper in the request I can ask the other party to reformat it. What would it look like if formatted properly? And if changed would I simply need to run json.loads on both the entire request and again on the nested value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186504/discussion-between-hikalea-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: @Hikalea: I added the correct format to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have received a JSON document with a nested JSON document, itself containing further JSON documents, inside one another like a [Matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Unfortunately, you can only decode one level, because the next level is *broken*. There should be `\` escapes in front of the `"` quote characters used for the 3rd level of JSON documents, just like the second level quotes were escaped when it was embedded in the top-level JSON document. Those are missing so no JSON parser can decode it anymore. The delimiters around JSON strings have been derailed by stray, unescaped `"` characters that were meant to be part of a JSON string value.

You either need to repair the *client* sending this data, and discard these malformed values as an invalid request.

For completeness sake, a *valid* document would look like this:

```
>>> v0 = '''{ "ReferenceValue":"Elevation", "Prediction":"22.216558464"}'''
>>> v1 = '''{ "ReferenceValue":"Wind Speed", "Prediction":"42.216558464"}" }'''
>>> data_value = json.dumps({'Value0': v0, 'Value1': v1})
>>> print(json.dumps({'Data': data_value, 'Date': '1/4/2019 9:52:2', 'DeviceId': '192-2993-2993', 'Key': '{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}', 'Location': '-1.000000000,-1.000000000'}, indent=4))
{
    "Data": "{\"Value0\": \"{ \\\"ReferenceValue\\\":\\\"Elevation\\\", \\\"Prediction\\\":\\\"22.216558464\\\"}\", \"Value1\": \"{ \\\"ReferenceValue\\\":\\\"Wind Speed\\\", \\\"Prediction\\\":\\\"42.216558464\\\"}\\\" }\"}",
    "Date": "1/4/2019 9:52:2",
    "DeviceId": "192-2993-2993",
    "Key": "{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}",
    "Location": "-1.000000000,-1.000000000"
}
```

Note the `\"` and `\\\"` escapes in the `Data` value. On decoding, the string value for `Data` will have one level of escape sequences removed, forming `"` and `\"` sequences, where the `"` quotes are part of the JSON syntax and `\"` are part of the string values, which in turn can be decoded to `"` used in the innermost JSON document.

Comment: That seems to be very close, if the initial request coming in already has / to escape quotes but is being stripped on the first json.loads(), do I need to escape TWICE on those nested 2 levels?

Comment: @Hikalea you’d decide nested documents with `json.load()`, *but you can’t here* because the nested document is broken.

Comment: @Hikalea it can’t be repaired either, not unless we know a lot more about what the normal structure would be and how this client constructed their query. Even then it may not be possible to recover.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends what you want to do with the data. You can loop through the 'Data' dictionary with:

```
for k,v in updatedRequest['Data'].items():
     # do some stuff
```

This will allow you to process without having to deal with the variable number of items in this dictionary. Hard to say what is best without knowing exactly what you wish to do though!